# Create repetitive UI for Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

From an API call in am getting list of object which varies, and i need to show the values in a Label and a EntryCell which changes for every API call as well as the number object also changes.

Any lead to it is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I undestand you correctly, but seems like what you're looking for is a [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/). You should go look at the link. And based from what you are specifically looking for, you're gonna need to use ViewCell.

Hope it helps!